# RTMP Live Streaming for Android Web Browsers?

Tags: android, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

I have a basic Wowza setup and tested live broadcasting out from "files" first, using Wirecast Transcoder. *(Later will be from a TV stream or something)*. Ok whatever then, via wowza, i can playback in Web Browsers for FLASH `RTMP` and iOS Devices `HTML5/m3u8`.

So my question is:

- What do i need to do to make Android Browsers (NON-FLASH / NON-m3u8) to be able to play my live streams? (What kind of Formats are needed for such Devices. `mp4? mov?` I don't know)

Please kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Got it simply!

```
<a href="rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live/channel-1"> View on Android </a>
```

Thats all!

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice is H.264 over RTSP (RTP should work too). See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119947/streaming-video-or-progressive-download-to-the-droid-browser/8373281#8373281) on a similar question.

Of course, using RSTP will not play on the browser but will open the video player. Note that the biggest difference regarding streaming is Android < 2.2 doesn't support Flash. Android 3.0 introduced Apple HTTP Live Streaming, so you could use this same stream for iOS and Android > 3.0 devices. Again, it won't play on the browser as an embedded Flash player would do, it will launch the native video player.

Probably the easier setup would be to have HTTP Live Streaming for Android 3.0 onwards and iOS, then RSTP for the rest.

Comment: Thanks! But I got my own simple solution as above just now. Thanks.

Comment: which solution you have found?  because i am facing same issue.  Please help me.

Comment: can you share your solution? im experiencing same issue :D

Comment: @夏期劇場 what is your solution?